# Problem in changing target framework in visual studio 2017 (xamarin)

Tags: xamarin

i am new to Xamarin.
i have a problem changing target framework. below i described the problem.
Before.

```
[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]
[enter image description here][3]
[enter image description here][4]
**After:**
[enter image description here][5]
[enter image description here][6]
[enter image description here][7]
[enter image description here][8]

*Please help.*


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgmPa.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx6mG.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1w0Q.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe3Oj.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/16Jn7.png
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyrFH.png
  [7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Urc8.png
  [8]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQumk.png
```

Comment: I posted an anwer for your problem, please see whether it can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The Target Framework (also known as compileSdkVersion) is the specific Android framework version (API level) that your app is compiled for at build time.

> The Target Framework identifies which library versions your
>   application is linked against – this setting determines which APIs you
>   can use in your app. For example, if you want to use the
>   NotificationBuilder.SetCategory method that was introduced in Android
>   5.0 Lollipop, you must set the Target Framework to API Level 21 (Lollipop) or later. If you set your project's Target Framework to an
>   API level such as API Level 19 (KitKat) and try to call the
>   SetCategory method in your code, you will get a compile error.

For more details about the Target Framework, please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=windows).

From the error message you posted, we can see:  Package Xamarin.Android.Support.XXX is not compatible with monoandroid51.Package

Recommend that you always compile with the latest available Target Framework version. Using the latest Target Framework version is especially important when you use the latest support library releases – each library expects your app to be compiled at that support library's minimum API level or greater.